# How to retrieve a value from two table using sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to retrieve value from two table and display it in a recyclerview so far i have tried joins but the results doesn't seems as i expected. Now let me post my problem in detail i have two table namely call and travel here is the data as below:

Call Table;

```
PK_ID  INC_ID   DES   CHECKIN  CHECKOUT  FLAG
-----  ------   ---   -------  --------  ----
 1       2      Test  12:20    14:50      1
```

Travel Table:

```
PK_ID  INC_ID   LAT   LONG  FLAG
-----  ------   ---   ----  ----
   1     2      11.4  11.5   2
```

My Expected result shoulbe something like this:

```
Caal_PK_ID    Travel_PK_Id   INC_ID   Checkin  Checkout FLAG  LAT    LONG
----------    ------------   ------   -------  -------- ----  ---    ----
   1                0          2       12:20     14:50   1     null  null 

   0                1          2        null      null   2     11.4  11.5
```

How to produce this desired result by using joins am getting combined results i don't want that i need results like this how can  i query this let me post my what i have tried so far

```
 String visitquery= "SELECT * FROM " + VisitModel.Visit_Table + " ,"  + VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable  + " where "   +VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID + " =  "+  id +  " and " +  VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID  + " = " + id ;
```

not getting results at can anyone please post anysolution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to try **JOIN** For the table, here i have modified your query to use **INNER JOIN** feature which will return the result that you want.

```
"SELECT * FROM " + VisitModel.Visit_Table + " as v INNER JOIN"  + VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable  + " as t where "   +v.Visit_IncidentID + " =  "+  id +  " and " +  v.Visit_IncidentID  + " = " + id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compose a simple sqlite join:

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT call.PK_ID, 
                                   travel.PK_Id,
                                   call.INC_ID,
                                   travel.INC_ID,
                                   call.CHECKIN,  
                                   call.CHECKOUT,   
                                   call.FLAG,  
                                   travel.FLAG,  
                                   travel.LAT  ,  
                                   travel.LONG 
                                 FROM table_call call
                                 INNER JOIN table_travel travel ON call.INC_ID=travel.INC_ID 
                                 WHERE call.INC_ID =?;
//I used your columns, you can use any column you'd like

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(myIncidentId)});
```

Note: if you are retrieving all the columns, you will have to inspect your cursor to select all rows correctly, so you will have to create a model, or to initialize both entities with the same cursor.

This query will return this schema of rows:

```
call.PK_ID    travel.PK_ID   call.INC_ID   travel.INC_ID   call.CHECKIN    call.CHECKOUT    call.FLAG    travel.FLAG    trvel.LAT    travel.LONG
----------    -----------     ----------   -------------   ------------    -------------    ---------    -----------    ---------     -----------
    1             1                2              2             12:20         14:50             1             2            11.4            11.5
```

Hope this helps

Comment: will this query provides as i expected

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran I added the schema the query will return datas, in my opinion it's simpler also for you to inspect with a single row containing all datas. this will return a row like this for each linked pair the query will find

Comment: bro but i need to return all row not as single row.  I need it for the purpose need to display it in recyclerview

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran you are retrieving all rows with this.. each row contains the datas I showed you in my answer, try in in your code with debugger and you will see :)

Comment: am getting result like you shown but i need table value separately like i mentioned in question .

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran in your scenario you are retrieving two rows: one for the table A and one for the table B.. now, consider if you have like dunno 3 calls for a travel. in your case you will retrieve 6 rows! 3 will be the same (the travel) and 3 will be the different calls. in my query you will retrieve 3 rows with all datas, I don't get why you don't just try this. go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and try what I posted fixing tables and columns names..

Comment: in my case i need to fetch that results and show it in recyclerview then how do i differentiate between two  result need to display like result from call table as separate item and result from travel in separate item but in this case am getting as one result then how do i differentiate

Comment: ... you have to use a cursor for retrieving datas, simply cast values from call into a call object and values from travel into a travel object.. if I have a cursor with a value A and a value B I can put value A into object o and value B into object w.........

Comment: can you please share some example

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran DEBUG! I posted you all the needed code in my answer, please use it in your application and try. I can help but you gotta do some work too

Comment: my doubt is in this result how would i differentiate this data is from call and this is from travel.

Comment: [learn about aliases](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alias_syntax.htm). you name all columns as you like and you retrieve them from cursor

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't want to **JOIN** the tables (looking at your expected results), but want an individual row for each row in both tables. In that case, you're looking for a **UNION** query

Try this:

```
SELECT PK_ID AS CALL_PK_ID, Null as TRAVEL_PK_ID,  INC_ID,   CHECKIN,  CHECKOUT,  FLAG, Null as Lat, Null As Long
From VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS CALL_PK_ID, PK_ID AS TRAVEL_PK_ID, INC_ID, Null As CHECKIN, NULL AS CHECKOUT, FLAG, Lat, Long
FROM VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable
```

That should return your expected results.